# How to reconcile difference between Arpack manual and example?

Tags: arpack

The [ARPACK manual](http://li.mit.edu/Archive/Activities/Archive/CourseWork/Ju_Li/MITCourses/18.335/Doc/ARPACK/Lehoucq97.pdf) for `znaupd` on pp. 128–129 says:

> Mode 2:[...]
>  OP = inv[M]*A and B = M.
>  [...]
>  IDO = 1: compute Y = OP * Z and
> Z = B * X where
>  IPNTR(1) is the pointer into WORKD for X,
>  IPNTR(2) is
> the pointer into WORKD for Y,
>  IPNTR(3) is the pointer into WORKD for
> Z.

I interpret that as:

> When IDO=1, compute the matrix=vector product $$ Z = MX $$ and store
> the result Z at IPNTR(3) then compute another
> matrix-vector product $$ rhs = AZ $$ then solve the linear system
> $$MY = rhs $$ and store the result Y at IPNTR(2).

However, the example `zndrv3.f` does this:

> When IDO=1, compute the matrix-vector product $$ rhs = AX $$ Then
> solve the linear system $$ MY = rhs $$ and store the result Y
> at IPNTR(2).

Which seems contradictory since it lacks one of the multiplications by $M$ and doesn't store Z.

So I'm not sure what I should do. I tried to copy the example but it didn't work (seems like wrong solutions). There are other possible reasons it didn't work but this is one of them I want to confirm. There's a similar inconsistency for `dsaupd` and doing it like the examples works OK there.

Comment: Can you clarify, what exactly "didn't work" means and formulate what exactly is the contradiction between the example and the documentation? That can help the community to find a solution to the problem.

Comment: In programming terms, operations are executed left-to-right, so the statement in a strict reading says that `Y=OP*Z` is computed with the input `Z`, and then the output `Z`, overwriting the input in the referenced array, is computed as `Z=B*M`. This would also be slightly more useful for the solution of the generalized eigenvalue problem.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Perhaps but that doesn't agree with the example and seems like a stretch for what the manual says.